# Serialização/desserialização XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialização, desserialização

Não consigo utilizar os dados que eu faço a desserialização do XML, não ocorre nenhuma exceção nem nada parecido...
Já fiz a verificação do caminho, dados porem não consigo listar os dados...

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Implement>
  <Locais>
    <Local>Tipo1</Local>
  </Locais>
  <TempoResposta>12</TempoResposta>
  <Auxilio>S</Auxilio>
</Implement>
```

Classe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Liber.Util
{
    public class XMLConnectionString
    {
        [XmlRoot("Locais"), XmlType("Locais")]
        public class Locais
        {
            [XmlElement("Local")]
            public string Local { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot("Implement"), XmlType("Implement")]
        public class Implement
        {
            [XmlElement("Locais")]
            public Locais Locais { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("TempoResposta")]
            public string TempoResposta { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("Auxilio")]
            public string Auxilio { get; set; }
        }
        
        public void desserializaConnectionString(string local)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(local);
            if (fi.Exists)
            {
                //ele entra aqui...
                
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(local, FileMode.Open);
                XmlRootAttribute xra = new XmlRootAttribute("Implement");
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Implement>), xra);
                List<Implement> lista = (List<Implement>)xs.Deserialize(fs);
                fs.Close();

                foreach(Implement c in lista)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(c.TempoResposta);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

De maneira alguma consigo realizar a impressão em tela através do:

```
MessageBox.Show(c.TempoResposta.ToString())
```

Ou

```
Console.Writeline(c.TempoResposta.ToString())
```

Ou até mesmo acessar os dados do objeto..
Alguém sabe o que pode ser ?

Answer (score 0):

Ola, para usar um `array` de elementos use `XmlArray` e para o elemento use `XmlArrayItem`

Na sua classe:

```
public class XMLConnectionString
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Locais")]
    public class Locais
    {
        [XmlElement("Local")]
        public string Local { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Implement")]
    public class Implement
    {
        [XmlElement("Locais")]
        public Locais Locais { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TempoResposta")]
        public string TempoResposta { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Auxilio")]
        public string Auxilio { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("ImplementCollection")]
    public class ImplementCollection
    {
        [XmlArray("Implements")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Implement", typeof(Implement))]
        public Implement[] list { get; set; }
    }

    public static void desserializaConnectionString(string local)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(local);
        if (fi.Exists)
        {
            ImplementCollection elements = null;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImplementCollection));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(local);
            elements = (ImplementCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(elements.list[0].TempoResposta);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Arquivo não existe.");
        }
    }
}
```

No seu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ImplementCollection> 
    <Implements> 
        <Implement> 
            <Locais>
                <Local>Tipo1</Local>
            </Locais>
            <TempoResposta>12</TempoResposta>
            <Auxilio>S</Auxilio>
        </Implement> 
        <Implement> 
            <Locais>
                <Local>Tipo1</Local>
            </Locais>
            <TempoResposta>12</TempoResposta>
            <Auxilio>S</Auxilio>
        </Implement> 
     </Implements> 
</ImplementCollection>
```

A estrutura do XML ficou `Classe->List->Items` isso porque criei uma classe para armazenar os items. se você precisar de uma lista use `elements.list.ToList();`

Para usar:

```
// Diretório Debug da aplicação.
XMLConnectionString.desserializaConnectionString("teste.xml");
```